# Generic entity model using doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create the generic seo table for different page types. For example, Page and Product etc will have the general seo tags like meta tile and discription. So I try to create the modal based on below diagram.

[image]

I am doing this on Symfony2 with doctrine. Problem is I don't know how to create the relationship correctly for with doctrine.

Relationships

```
page (id) (One to One)-> Seo type (entity_id)  
product (id) (One to One)-> Seo type (entity_id) 

seo entity type (id) (One to Many)-> Seo type (entity_type) 
seo (seo_entity) (One to One)-> Seo type (entity_type_id)
```

Can someone guide me, How can I do this with doctrine annotation. I have another question is Seo entity type table really required. Is there anyway to strip that table.

For above relationship, I created below annotation. But it's throwing error.

```
class Page
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SeoEntity", inversedBy="page")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="entity_id")
 *
 */
protected $entity_id;   

}


class SeoEntity
{

/** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="seoentity", cascade={"persist", "merge"}) */
protected $seo_entity_id;   

/** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SeoEntityMeta", mappedBy="seoentity", cascade={"persist", "merge"}) */
protected $seo_entity_meta_id;  

}


class SeoEntityMeta
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SeoEntity", inversedBy="seo_entity_meta")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
protected $seo_entity_id;

}
```

getting below error

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE Page ADD CONSTRAINT
>   FK_B438191E377A038C FOREIGN K     EY (seo_entity_id_id) REFERENCES
>   seo_entity (entity_id)':
>                                                                                                              SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'sf.#sql-3be_48' (errno: 150)
>                                                                               [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'sf.#sql-3be_48' (errno: 150)

Comment: Its up to you whether or not you need that table, as for annotations, you should try to use the documentation first. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: @Flosculus: I updated question with annotation that I tried. but it's not working. Can see what I am doing wrong in that

Comment: The mappedBy and inversedBy are all wrong.  Suggest using the command: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="MyBundle:Page" --format="annotation"`, replace `MyBundle` with your bundle name.  After that you can see how it generated, you dont need to suffix your property names with `_id` though, doctrine does this for you in the DB